# How do I sum the values in the last column of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `<Label>` under a `<DataGrid>` where I would display the sum of values in the LAST column.
Any questions and answers I found are either deprecated or about `<DataGridView>` (e.g. `grid.Rows` / `.Items[*].Cells`).

[image: Visual]

The Label for the sum:

```
<Label Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" MinWidth="50" Padding="0"
       Content="{Binding Path=JobTotalSum, ConverterCulture='sk-SK', StringFormat=C}"/>
```

Binding value:

```
public float JobTotalSum
{
    get
    {
        float sum = 0f;
        for(int i = 0; i < JobDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            //DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)JobDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            //JobDataGrid.Columns[^1].GetCellContent(row);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

The custom class for datagrid items:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Faktura
{
    class Job
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public float Length { get; set; }
        public float HourlyWage { get; set; }
        public float Sum => Length * HourlyWage;
    }
}
```

The DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="JobDataGrid" Style="{StaticResource JobMaterialTable}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="8*" Header="Názov a druh práce" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource LeftAlignHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftAlign}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="2*" Header="Čas" Binding="{Binding Path=Length, ConverterCulture='sk-SK', StringFormat='0.# h'}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Header="Hodinová sadzba" Binding="{Binding Path=HourlyWage, ConverterCulture='sk-SK', StringFormat=C}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="2*" Header="Spolu" Binding="{Binding Path=Sum, ConverterCulture='sk-SK', StringFormat=C}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <!-- Table Content -->
    <local:Job Name="Oprava" Length=".5" HourlyWage="20"/>
    <local:Job Name="Oprava" Length="2" HourlyWage="20"/>
    <local:Job Name="Oprava" Length="2" HourlyWage="20"/>
    <local:Job Name="Oprava" Length="2" HourlyWage="20"/>
    <local:Job Name="Oprava" Length="2" HourlyWage="20"/>

</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not doing the sum using the rows and cell content, but using the data source itself. Can you access the data source of the grid in your code?

It could be something like this:

```
using System.Linq; // to use LINQ extension method - Enumerable.Sum

// ...

public float JobTotalSum
{
    get
    {
        var data = JobDataGrid.ItemsSource; // or better yet, maybe you have a reference to the original data source that's bound to the datagrid?
        var sum = data.Sum(item => item.LastColumn); // replace 'LastColumn' with the name of the property that is shown in the last column
        return sum;
    }
}
```

This can be improved upon, depending on your context. For example, you may want to calculate the sum once (on page load, for example), instead of doing it in the getter.

Comment: I'm dynamically adding objects to the DataGrid (planning on to hook it up on property change - the data in the image are static just for testing). Your code throws `'IEnumerable< >' does not contain a definition for 'Sum'`. I also made it a one liner `public float JobTotalSum => JobDataGrid.ItemsSource.Sum(item => item.Sum);` - The property is of a Custom Class - maybe the problem (Interface missing?).

Comment: Add `using System.Linq` to the using statements. But my point is not about how you calculate the sum (with a loop or using LINQ), my point is to use the data source, not the values in the GUI components.

Comment: I added the using, error still persists. Your answer looks good so I'm marking it as such. Any idea why isn't the Linq function recognized?

Comment: Strange, System.Linq has been a part of every version of .NET for a while now. What's your .NET version, and which IDE are you using?

Comment: .NET Core 3.1, MS VS. Is it missing Linq? The IDE doesn't label the using as unnecessary....

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 should be definitely fine. Is the error actually at `...ItemsSource.Sum(...` or at `... => item.Sum);`? Is `Sum` the name of a property of your items' type?

Comment: Updated the question. Error is just the Sum function being unrecognized (only that part underlined)

Comment: It's hard to say why the Sum method cannot be found without seeing the whole code. You can of course avoid using that method and do the addition "manually", with a `for` or `foreach` loop, for example.

You may also find something useful here: https://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-sum/ and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Single__

Comment: Yeah, sure! I didn't know about ItemsSource, that's what I needed, thank you kind person on the internet.